# How to sort alphanumeric characters in java?

Tags: java

I want to sort Q4,Q7,Q2,Q1 to Q1,Q2,Q4,Q7.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example would be fine to just sort with the natural order of strings. However, presumably you could have "Q10" which should come after "Q7"?

Comment: Could you give example for how to sort this?

Comment: What is the format of the entries? Is it any single non-digit followed by a single digit / multiple digits? What is the order precedence? Character first, then digit?

Comment: @Vasu: You still haven't said what "this" is - one digit or potentially multiple?

Comment: It is multiple , ie from Q1 to Q100 - first alphabet then next number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Collections.Sort method with String comparators or can write your own comparator for the same.

Sample

```
String [] str = new String[]{"Q4","Q7","Q2","Q1"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);

        Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

String implements Comparable. Depending how you hold them, i.e using a List or an array, you can use Collections.sort() and Arrays.sort() respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own comparator, ie:

```
public class ComparatorSO implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(1));
        Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.substring(1));
        return i1.compareTo(i2);

    }

}
```

Not tested, and assuming that the input strings are of the form Qn with n int. The question is not very clear though.